# Стереть содержимое всех текстовых файлов в папке

Tags: linux

не могу стереть содержимое всех текстовых файлов в папке.
испробовал разные способы, не получается
Пытался использовать cp /dev/null * 
писало ошибку

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос команду, которой Вы пытались это сделать.

Comment: А понятие "текстовый" у вас согласно его mime-type? А как вы определяете зулусский язык в Unicode, например?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

что бы "стереть содержимое файлов", можно просто обрезать их размер до нуля. Для этого есть команда `truncate --size 0 <имяфайла>`. Найти все файлы к каталоге (рекурсивно) можно такой командой `find . -type f` (где точка - текущий каталог).

Соединяем. Вначале запускаем

```
find . -type f
```

и смотрим на список файлов, что он соответствует требуемому. Если все ок, запускаем такое

```
find . -type f -exec truncate --size 0 {} \;
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

команда

```
$ cp /dev/null файл
```

запишет в `файл` (в самое начало) строку нулевой длины, тем самым **как бы** «сотрёт» содержимое файла.

аналогичное действие произведёт и такая, например, команда:

```
$ cat /dev/null > файл
```

или такая:

```
$ : > файл
```

или такая:

```
$ truncate -s 0 файл
```

---

а чтобы произвести это действие со всеми файлами в текущем каталоге (и подкаталогах), можно, например, воспользоваться программой *find*:

```
$ find -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

это если использовать вариант без перенаправления ввода/вывода (проще говоря — без `>`).

если же требуется использовать перенаправление, придётся вызывать интерпретатор оболочки. с приведёнными выше вариантами:

```
$ find -type f -exec sh -c 'cp /dev/null > {}' \;
$ find -type f -exec sh -c 'cat /dev/null > {}' \;
$ find -type f -exec sh -c ': > {}' \;
```

---

#### по поводу текстовых файлов

если требуется определить именно **текстовый** файл (на основе его содержимого), то, как советуют, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659891/4827341), можно использовать опцию `-I` программы *grep*.

тогда в команду (например):

```
$ find -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

надо добавить вызов программы *grep*:

```
$ find -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -and -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

аналогично и для других примеров.

Comment: А зачем `:` в `: > file.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё полезная программа `shred`

> Переписывает несколько раз указанные файлы для того, чтобы сделать
>   более сложным восстановление даже с использованием очень дорогого
>   оборудования.

Пример использования:

```
$ shred -n5 -z /dir_for_shred/*
```

Команда `shred` с ключом `-n` перезаписывает 5 раз все файлы в директории  `dir_for_shred` и с ключом `-z` перезаписывает в конце нулями, чтобы скрыть измельчение.

Более подробная информация в `man shred` или `shred --help`

Answer (score -1):

```
cp /dev/null file.txt
```

Вот это попробуй сделать, может поможет.

Comment: я этот способ знаю, но он для одного файла, а мне нужно для всех в папке.

Comment: пытался cp /dev/null *
но писало ошибку

Comment: Ну твои знания в линукcе какие?

Comment: ну более чем базовые

Comment: тогда попробуй команду cat /dev/null > file.txt

Comment: ну пaпку укажи вместо файл.тхт, но этот способ работал на гентухе

Comment: @Coder956, yet another *useless use of cat*. И `cp /dev/null` тоже ни к чему. Учите shell — это очень сложный язык, чтобы на нём писать красиво, лаконично и переносимо. (`> file.txt` будет работать везде)

Comment: @0andriy жыз это троллинг был